# Joda - DateTimeFormatter - print day of a week as a shortcut

Tags: android, datetime, string-formatting, jodatime, datetime-format

I'm using DateTimeFormatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.fullDate();
dateTimeFormatter.print(...);
```

I need to print full date but the day of a week should be displayed as a shortcut. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet here is to inspect the format of `DateTimeFormat.fullDate()` and then reconstruct it yourself using a pattern. In my Locale (English/Australia):

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.fullDate();
System.out.println(dtf.print(DateTime.now()));
//result: Sunday, May 7, 2017
```

So I would use the following pattern to get the abbreviated day of week:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E, MMM d, YYYY");
System.out.println(dtf.print(DateTime.now()));
//result: Sun, May 7, 2017
```

Note that "E" and "EEE" are the two patterns for abbreviated day of week and full day of week. Refer to the [javadoc for DateTimeFormat](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) for a list of patterns

Comment: How can I inspect and reconstruct when DateTimeFormatter works on different Locales (Android) ?

Comment: @AppiDevo use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html rather than joda if you want that

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

Quoted below is a notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        // Replace ZoneId.systemDefault(), which specifies the JVM's default time zone,
        // as applicable e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        // 1. Using DayOfWeek
        // Replace Locale.ENGLISH as per the desired Locale
        String dayName = today.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dayName);

        // 2. Using DateTimeFormatter
        // Replace Locale.ENGLISH as per the desired Locale
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E", Locale.ENGLISH);
        dayName = dtf.format(today);
        System.out.println(dayName);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Tue
Tue
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>